Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string '36' while running borrow function on Lending Pool contract
const { getWeth, AMOUNT } = require("../scripts/getWeth")

async function main() {
    await getWeth()
    let { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    let signer = await ethers.provider.getSigner(deployer)
    let lendingPoolAddresses = await getLendingPoolAddress(signer)
    //weth tooken address,lendingpooladdress,amount,signer
    await approveSpender("0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2", lendingPoolAddresses, signer)
    let lendingPool = await ethers.getContractAt("ILendingPool", lendingPoolAddresses, signer)
    await lendingPool.supply("0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2", AMOUNT, signer, 0)
    const { totalCollateralBase, totalDebtBase } = await lendingPool.getUserAccountData(signer)
    console.log(`You have collateral:${totalCollateralBase}`)

    console.log(`You have borrowed:${totalDebtBase}`)

    let daiPrice = await getDaiPrice()
    const amountDaiToBorrow = totalCollateralBase.toString() * 0.95 * (1 / daiPrice.toString())
    const amountDaiToBorrowWei = ethers.parseEther(amountDaiToBorrow.toString())
    console.log(`You can borrow ${amountDaiToBorrow.toString()} DAI`)
    //borrowing 95% of collateralised asset
    await borrowDai(lendingPool, deployer, amountDaiToBorrowWei)
}
async function getDaiPrice() {
    let tx = await ethers.getContractAt(
        "AggregatorV3Interface",
        "0xAed0c38402a5d19df6E4c03F4E2DceD6e29c1ee9",
    )
    let daiPrice = (await tx.latestRoundData())[1]
    console.log(`The price of DAI is ${daiPrice.toString()}`)
    return daiPrice
}
async function borrowDai(lendingPoolContract, borrowerAddress, amountDaiToBorrowWei) {
    let tx = await lendingPoolContract.borrow(
        "0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f",
        amountDaiToBorrowWei,
        1,
        0,
        borrowerAddress,
    )
    await tx.wait(1)
    console.log("Congrats ,you have successfully borrowed ")
}
async function getLendingPoolAddress(signer) {
    let lendingPool = await ethers.getContractAt(
        "IPoolAddressesProvider",
        "0x2f39d218133AFaB8F2B819B1066c7E434Ad94E9e",
        signer,
    )
    let lendingPoolAddresses = await lendingPool.getPool()

    return lendingPoolAddresses
}
async function approveSpender(tokenAddress, spenderAddress, signer) {
    let erc20 = await ethers.getContractAt("IERC20", tokenAddress, signer)
    let tx = await erc20.approve(spenderAddress, AMOUNT)
    await tx.wait(1)
    console.log("successfully approved")
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))


This returns the following error
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string '36'
    at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0x87870bca3f3fd6335c3f4ce8392d69350b4fa4e2)
    at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0x87870bca3f3fd6335c3f4ce8392d69350b4fa4e2)
    at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0x87870bca3f3fd6335c3f4ce8392d69350b4fa4e2)
    at EdrProviderWrapper.request (/home/raaghavmanivel/hardhat-defi/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:415:41)
    at HardhatEthersSigner.sendTransaction (/home/raaghavmanivel/hardhat-defi/node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers/src/signers.ts:125:18)
    at send (/home/raaghavmanivel/hardhat-defi/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:313:20)
    at Proxy.borrow (/home/raaghavmanivel/hardhat-defi/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:352:16)
    at borrowDai (/home/raaghavmanivel/hardhat-defi/scripts/aaveBorrow.js:35:14)
    at main (/home/raaghavmanivel/hardhat-defi/scripts/aaveBorrow.js:23:5)

I tried changing the Interest Mode between 1 and 2, but the same error persists. The other functions are working perfectly..

Error Code 36 is COLLATERAL_CANNOT_COVER_NEW_BORROW (https://github.com/aave/aave-v3-core/blob/b74526a7bc67a3a117a1963fc871b3eb8cea8435/contracts/protocol/libraries/helpers/Errors.sol#L45)
This code is attempting to borrow 95% of collateral value which is higher than the maximum LTV (loan-to-value ratio) of this collateral asset. To calculate the exact percentage that can be borrowed you can either:
(a) Calculate using availableBorrowsBase from Pool.getUserAccountData (https://etherscan.io/address/0x87870Bca3F3fD6335C3F4ce8392D69350B4fA4E2#readProxyContract#F24). availableBorrowsBase / borrowAssetOraclePrice = maxBorrowAmount
or
(b) Calculate borrowing power for an individual collateral token using ltv parameter from PoolDataProvider.getReserveConfigurationData(https://etherscan.io/address/0x20e074f62ecbd8bc5e38211adcb6103006113a22#readContract#F13). (collateralTokenBalance * collateralTokenOraclePrice * ltv) / borrowAssetOraclePrice = maxBorrowAmount
